# Cannot recieve feedback from iOS Push Notification using PHP

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I have set up a php file on my own server and used it to send push notifications. I have already tried it with two devices and it works well. The problem is with the feedback method which returns nothing. I have already tried everything and disabled firewall and so on. Note that i tested the feedback like this: I run the app on both devices. They both get the notification. then i delete the app on one of them and try again. Here is the PHP code i used:

```
<?php

$deviceToken1 = '.....';
$deviceToken2 = '.....';

$tokenArr = array($deviceToken1,$deviceToken2);

$passphrase = '.....';

$message = $_POST['message'];
$newsID = $_POST['newsID'];

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

for($i = 0; $i < count($tokenArr); $i++) 
{ 
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'badge' => 1,
        'sound' => 'sound.aiff',
        'newsID' => $newsID);

    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

        // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $tokenArr[$i]) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

        if (!$result) {
              echo '<br/>'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").' Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;  
        } 
        else {
              echo '<br/>'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").' Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
        }
}

stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
echo $apns;
if(!$apns) 
{
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "Error $errcode : $errstr\n";
        return;
}
else {

    echo "APNS feedback results\n";
    while ($devcon = fread($fp, 38))
        {
        $arr = unpack("H*", $devcon); 
        $rawhex = trim(implode("", $arr));
        $feedbackTime = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 0, 8)); 
        $feedbackDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', $feedbackTime); 
        $feedbackLen = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 8, 4)); 
        $feedbackDeviceToken = substr($rawhex, 12, 64);
        echo "TIMESTAMP:" . $feedbackDate . "\n";
        echo "DEVICE ID:" . $feedbackDeviceToken. "\n\n";
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: Feedback method? It's difficult to tell exactly what you mean by this. Post your objective-c code so we can see what you're doing in your app.

Comment: @davetw12 i would but this is pretty common when working with ios push notifications. And it has nothing to do with the objective C code. You probably dont have any idea what im talking about.